# Start changing color again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have my control script, which changes color of the sprites. When I click onto the sprite it falls and stops changing color. On collision it checks whether the color is the same, then it teleports the sprite back up. So now my question is: How can I make it change the color again?

My color changer:

```
public class control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool m_isRunning = false;
    public static bool loop = true;
    public SpriteRenderer m_spriteRenderer;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public static int random;
    public static float loopdelay = 0f;
    public static float intervalplayer = 1f; //interval 
    public static bool changecolorborder = true;
    public static bool fall = false;
    public static int gravity = 0;
    public static bool transform1 = false;

    private void Update()
    {
       random = Random.Range(1, 4);
        if (fall)
        {
            rb.gravityScale = gravity;
        }
        if (transform1)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0.002f, 1.998f, 0);
        }
        if(Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Helloo");
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {

        m_spriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        StartCoroutine(Changecolor(0f));

    }

    private IEnumerator Changecolor(float loopdelay)
    {
        while (loop)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervalplayer);
            if (loop)
            {
                if (random == 1)
                {
                    Color newColor = new Color(0.68f, 0.63f, 0.76f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
                }
                else if (random == 2)
                {
                    Color newColor = new Color(0.89f, 0.25f, 0.23f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
                }
                else if (random == 3)
                {
                    Color newColor = new Color(0.68f, 0.88f, 0.33f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    Color newColor = new Color(0.38f, 0.21f, 0.72f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        fall = true;
        loop = !loop;
        gravity = 1;
        changecolorborder = !changecolorborder;
    }




}
```

My collision checker:

```
public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static float waitime = 1f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Text textMy = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();

        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color != gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color)
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            textMy.text = counter.ToString();
            control.gravity = 0;
            StartCoroutine(waitfor());

        }

    }
    IEnumerator waitfor()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        control.transform1 = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.033f);
        control.transform1 = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess reseting your values like in the beggining

```
fall = false;
loop = true;
gravity = 0;
changecolorborder = !changecolorborder;
```

And calling the coroutine again

```
StartCoroutine(Changecolor(0f));
```